# Converting an NSColor to a UIColor from an NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor, nscolor

I am trying to check the colour of specific words in an attributed string. I can access the attribute but can't convert this attribute dictionary into a UIColor.

First I enumerate over my attributed string, this returns, for each different attributed, a dictionary of the attributes. I can then look closer at each.

```
NSAttributedString * attributes = self.textView.attributedText;

[attributes enumerateAttributesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, attributes.length) options:0 usingBlock:^(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull attrs, NSRange range, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {


}];
```

When I return the attrs dictionary I get this (with HKWMentionAttributeName being a subclass I am using):

```
{
    HKWMentionAttributeName = "<0x610000243450> (HKWMentionsAttribute) text: ABC name 1, id: uY5Vv8QzBxhPoB8jTxUBeBmTaeD3, no range";
    NSColor = "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fd388558ce0> font-family: \".SFUIText\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 19.00pt";
}
```

I then access the color with `attrs[@"NSColor"];` and it is returned as below:

```
UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to turn this into a UIColor or even begin to use this object.

I understand that the `1 0 0 1` are the red, green, blue and alpha but I don't know how to access them to use the `colorWithRed` function.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682923/convert-nscolor-to-rgb) seems to suggest I need to change the color space but it doesn't give much more of an explanation than that.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23924025/ios-use-of-nscolor-versus-uicolor) makes me feel that I shouldn't be trying to import the NSColor class as it is an OSX class

I have tried all my usual color go-tos: attempting to load as a `CGColor`, a `CIColor`, loading `CGColorGetComponents`, loading it as an `NSString`, loading it as an `id` to see if this would shine more light on the issue.

I feel this is a problem with my understanding of `UIColor` and `NSColor` objects but there is very little information I can find which helps convert between the two.

Comment: Are you sure that the object actually is an `NSColor`? This seems odd, since one would expect `NSColor` not to be present on iOS. What do you get if you run `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([attrs[@"NSColor"] class]));`?

Comment: When I do that it says it is a `UICachedDeviceRGBColor`

Comment: That's what I expected. One moment.

Comment: The error says it all.  Change the color space.

Comment: @ElTomato how do I change the color space? I have searched for this (before posting) and couldn't find anything more than the link provided which doesn't give any details on how to do it.

Comment: @simon_smiley Since more experienced people say otherwise, I have nothing more to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@"NSColor"`, despite coincidentally sharing the name of an AppKit class, is simply the raw value of the `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` constant. On iOS, this is documented to be a `UIColor`. Therefore, you should just be able to take `attrs[NSForegroundColorAttributeName]`, cast it to a `UIColor`, and use it.

Comment: I think that's a slippery slope.  How do you know that they share the exact same color space?

Comment: @ElTomato No "slope". The OP was wrong ever to look at the string name. This _is_ `.foregroundColor`.

Comment: @ElTomato There's nothing weird here. Simply do: `UIColor *color = attrs[NSForegroundColorAttributeName];`. That's it. Done.